# better approach then setTimeout on Google Map V3

Tags: javascript, dictionary, settimeout, marker, geocode

in my Asp.net Web Application where i am using the setTimeout to Get rid of
geocoder OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, the shorter time out is 10ms which is too longer for me, I have 800 above addresses coming from SQL SERVER which would be increased because of this setTimeout will take about 5 to 7 mints to take places of all the markers on map and that`s frustrating.  I researched and saw this link [setTimeout: how to get the shortest delay](http://ajaxian.com/archives/settimeout-delay)

but cant figure out what he want to do actually. please someone guide me....

```
    function InitializeMap() {       
    // Here am calling the webService by PageMethods in which CityNames, Countries Name will take their places 
    PageMethods.GetCitiesbyUser_Extender(onSucess);

    var myOptions =
    {
       zoom: 0, 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    // Creating latlngbound to bound the markers on map
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 

    //// Creating an array that will contain the addresses 
    var places = []; 
    // Creating a variable that will hold the InfoWindow object 
    var infowindow; 
    // create this to add the marker Cluster on map
    mc = new  MarkerClusterer(map);
    var popup_content = [];
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    // image for ballon i want to change default ballon to this
    var iconimage = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=mm&chs=24x32&chco=FFFFFF,008CFF,000000&ext=.png";        
    var markers = [];

    // Create this function for passing the values which was taken by webservice cntName is the return in webservice 
    function onSucess(cntName){
    // loop through the cntName to pass the individual City one by one from geocode
        for (i = 0; i < cntName.length; ++i) {
               //for  fixing the issue use closure to localize the cntName[i] variable before passing into geocode and callback function within it.
            (function CreateMarkAndInfo(address) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },
                    function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            places[i] = results[0].geometry.location;

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: places[i],
                                title: results[0].formatted_address,
                                map: map,
                                icon: iconimage
                            });

                            markers.push(marker);
                            mc.addMarker(marker);
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                if (!infowindow) {
                                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                                }

                                // Setting the content of the InfoWindow afterward
                                infowindow.setContent(popup_content[i]);

                                // Tying the InfoWindow to the marker afterward
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            });

                            // Extending the bounds object with each LatLng 
                            bounds.extend(places[i]);

                            // Adjusting the map to new bounding box 
                            map.fitBounds(bounds);
                            // Zoom out after fitBound
                            var listener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
                                if (map.getZoom() < 10) map.setZoom(2);

                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            // if geocode will end the limit then make delay by timer in order to avoid the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                                setTimeout(function () { CreateMarkAndInfo(address); }, (15)); // here i think i should use better approch but for now it`s ok.                                   
                            }

                            else {
                                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                            }  
                        }                            
                    });

            })(cntName[i]);// End closure trick     
        }  
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', InitializeMap);
```

**Edit:**
@just.another.programmer i cant because there is no latitute and longitude in DB, client will add cities and countries by him self thats why i had to convet city and country names by geocode and geocode doing it`s job accuretly here
How i am calling the City and country Names by web service

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    public static string[] GetCitiesbyUser_Extender()
    {       
        System.Data.DataSet dtst = new System.Data.DataSet();
        string ses = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
        USTER.Dal.clsSearch clssearch = new USTER.Dal.clsSearch();
        // Assinging the Stroed Procedure Method to DataSet
        dtst = clssearch.GetAllCitiesByUser(ses);
        string[] cntName = new string[dtst.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow rdr in dtst.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                // Columns Name in SQL Server Table "CityName" and "CountryName"
                cntName.SetValue(rdr["CityName"].ToString() +","+ rdr["CountryName"].ToString() , i);
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {

        }
        return cntName;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.webstutorial.com/google-server-side-geocoding-php-infobox/website-tweaks/google

Answer (score 0):

Geocode your addresses one time when you first get them, then store the lat/long in your db so you don't have to geocode again.  This will *dramatically* reduce your geocode requests and remove the need for `setTimeout`.

Comment: i cant because database in production server and am not allowed to edit database tables, but only can create the proc and function

Comment: sweet talk your dba into changing the tables for you.  you really don't want to be re-geocoding the same data for every person who uses your site.

Comment: yup you right i really dont want to same data for every person it will dynamically change according to users role, did`nt you see the "UserName" session which i passed into WebService?